# In TeamCity, is there a way of seeing a report of tests ordered by failed-most-often across the whole history?

Tags: automated-tests, teamcity, data-mining

We have some unreliable tests - unreliable because of environmental reasons.

We'd like to see a history of which tests have failed the most often, so we can drill into why and fix the environment issue that causes that particular failure or class of failure.

Is this possible in TeamCity 6.0.3?

We know about individual test history (although that page is really hard to remember how to find!), but that pre-supposes we already know what we're actually trying to find out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you go to the "Current problems" tab for a project, there is a link like "tests failed within 120 hours" at the top. There is some statistics which may be relevant to what you're looking for.

**UPDATE:** In newer versions of TeamCity, this page is not available. But, there is a new *Flaky tests* tab, which shows information about tests which fail un-predictably, and this page includes test failure counters.

Comment: Is there a way to get to that view when the build is not broken...?

Comment: Use URL like /project.html?projectId=project123&tab=tests where project123 - ID of your project

Comment: Oh the irony of needing to fix tests that are passing!